# Read binary file with C++ and translate some contents in it

Tags: c++, winapi, binary, binary-data

I am trying to learn more about binary files, so I started with HexEdit, and I manually wrote a file and created a template for it. Here is my work:

[image]

Now, I started working on a console application in C++ Win32 to read the contents in that file and make them look friendly. Here is part my code:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

long getFileSize(FILE *file)
{
    long lCurPos, lEndPos;
    lCurPos = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, 2);
    lEndPos = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, lCurPos, 0);
    return lEndPos;
}

int main()
{
    const char *filePath = "D:\\Applications\\ColorTableApplication\\file.clt";
    BYTE *fileBuf;          // Pointer to our buffered data
    FILE *file = NULL;      // File pointer

    if ((file = fopen(filePath, "rb")) == NULL)
        printf_s("Could not open specified file\n");
    else {
        printf_s("File opened successfully\n");
        printf_s("Path: %s\n", filePath);
        printf_s("Size: %d bytes\n\n", getFileSize(file));
    }

    long fileSize = getFileSize(file);

    fileBuf = new BYTE[fileSize];

    fread(fileBuf, fileSize, 1, file);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        printf("%X ", fileBuf[i]);
    }

    _getch();
    delete[]fileBuf;
        fclose(file);   // Almost forgot this 
    return 0;
}
```

(I provided that much code because I want to be clear, to help you get the idea about what I am trying to do)

First of all, I need to get the first 14 bytes and write them in the console as text, and then, in a `for` I need to write something like this for each color:

```
black      col_id = 1; R = 00; G = 00; B = 00;
red        col_id = 2; R = FF; G = 00; B = 00;
etc...
```

How can I read and translate these bytes?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want help with. I must say that I'm no convinced your format is "sane" - you have a string, that appears to not have any terminating zero ("lightgreen" takes up 10 bytes of a 10 byte field, as far as I can see). The format is also unaligned - and you say 14 bytes, but as far as I see it's 13 bytes.

Comment: sorry @MatsPetersson, by "the first 14 bytes`, I mean the first 14 bytes at the begining of my file: `ColorTableFile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct as you have it to write out the 14 bytes.

a technique is to create a struct with the layout of your records, then cast e.g. (C-style)

```
typedef struct
{
  char name[10];
  long col_id; 
  unsigned char R;
  unsigned char G;
  unsigned char B;
} rec;

rec* Record = (rec*)(fileBuf + StartOffsetOfRecords);
```

now you can get the contents of the first record

```
Record->name, ...
```

getting next record is just a matter of moving `Record` forward

```
++Record;
```

You could also have a struct for the header to make it more convenient to pickout the number of records, it is good to use stdint.h in order to get well defined sizes. also to pack structures on byte boundary to make sure no padding is done by the compiler i.e. `#pragma pack(1)` at the top of your source.

```
typedef struct 
{
  char signature[14];
  uint32_t tableaddress;
  uint32_t records; 
} header;

typedef struct
{
  char name[10]; 
  uint32_t col_id;
  unsigned char R;
  unsigned char B;
  unsigned char G;

} rec;
```

so instead when you read you could do like this

```
header Header;
rec* Record;

fread(&Header,sizeof(header),1,file);
fread(fileBuf,1,fileSize,file);

Record = (rec*)(fileBuf); // first record can be accessed through Record
```

Comment: I am working in Visual Studio. I have created a `Win32 Console Application project, so I am not yet sure if I am using C or C++, but my VS says the `cout is undefined`, `hex is undefined`, `setw is undefined` though I have `iostream` included.

Comment: sorry wasn't paying attention, your real question is about the following records. i have edited my reply again.

Comment: I will try it in a few minutes!

Comment: Tesintg your code, I realize, that I don't know how to type the number of records, that you put in the `Header` struct. If it helps you, in my binary file, it is 4 byte integer, starting at `0x000012`. If I use this line (`printf("Number of colors: %d\n", Header.records);`), it will always be `720896` instead of `11`

Comment: maybe you can fiddle a bit with the structure so it better fits your file, I have not tested the code I wrote, just gave you the principle.

Comment: you should also make sure you have structures packed on byte boundaries, this can be done by writing `#pragma pack(1)` at the top of your source code or as a compiler switch on your project. otherwise the compiler may pad the structs with bytes to get an even number

Comment: it is also better to use the data types in stdint.h (or cstdint for c++) to use types that are more portably defined. e.g. uint8 and uint32 instead of BYTE/unsigned char and long.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34684/discussion-between-claptrap-and-victor)